# Check "Use Default Value" for attribute in Magento using the API

Tags: php, magento

I know this type of question has been asked so many times before but I've not been able to find a solution using the API.

I'd like to know if there's a way to set an attribute to "Use Default Value" via the API so that both the Default and Website level are the same data.

I'm using SOAP V2 in PHP.

I've tried setting the value to FALSE at Website level but that hasn't worked.  I've tried this on a date, text and price field.

When I do it on a price or text field, it just empties the field at Website level and the "Use Default Value" checkbox is not ticked.  When I do it on a date field, it's either changed the date to be "01/01/1970" or it's emptied the field, again without the "Use Default Value" checkbox being ticked.

Comment: Did you get the answer.

Comment: no, I've not got anywhere with this to be honest :(